# embedXcode not fully working

Tags: xcode, arduino, arduino-ide

I've installed embedXcode in both my Laptop and my desktop computers to work on my Arduino hobby projects.

On my Laptop everything worked as expected and on the .ino file, after adding

```
#include <Arduino.h>
```

at the top of the file, the Xcode began recognizing the code, autofilling and so on.

On my desktop (the computer I usually work on), everything is installed ok, the project builds ok (and is uploaded on the Arduino board ok), but there is no code recognition (for the Arduino specific statements).

Any ideas on what could be wrong here? It's been driving me crazy for the whole afternoon...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the updated release that addresses this issue.

embedXcode  • Feb 08, 2014 release 131 • Improved indexing for code-sense